# Cannot get Laravel relationships working, newbie

Tags: php, join, laravel, eloquent

I started learning 2 days ago. I have made a simple user login and blog posting system.

Here is my code that will fetch all the blog posts, but should also join the tables together

```
public function index()
{
    $blog = new Blog;

    $view = View::make('blogs.index');
    $view->posts = $blog->get()->user;

    return $view;
}
```

Is this right? Looking at documentation and searching, it seems to be right but I keep getting the following error:

**Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$user**

My blog table is structed like this:
[image]

And user table like so
[image]

Blog Model

```
class Blog extends Eloquent {

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User', 'user_id', 'id');
    }
}
```

User Model

```
class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    use UserTrait, RemindableTrait;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'users';

    /**
     * The attributes excluded from the model's JSON form.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = array('password', 'remember_token');


    public function blog()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Blog', 'id', 'user_id');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `index()` function try this

```
public function index()
{
     $posts = Blog::all();

     return View::make('blogs.index', array('posts' => $posts));
}
```

And then in `blogs.index` you can access the relationship by (blade)

`{{ $posts->user->id }}`, `{{ $posts->user->email }}` or any column in your DB

Comment: Could you explain how it knows to always do the join? That bit has confused me

Comment: I wish I knew the deep technical reasons behind it but I'll try my best anyway! Laravel uses Eloquent inside it's models. Eloquent will automatically load your defined relationships for you and then you are able to access these relationships using something called 'dynamic properties'. Basically it's just really smart!

Answer (score 0):

With `$blog = new Blog;` you are starting to create a new blog entry.  What you really need to do is query the blog table and get the users, which can be done quite easily with eager loading.  Try this...

`$blogs = Blog::with('users');`

Then when you are creating your view, you want to send the blogs in your view using something like this...  The first parameter of the `with()` method is the name you want to give the variable inside your view and the second is the actual variable to send.

`return View::make('blogs.index')->with('blogs', $blogs);`